# Как получить элемент по id(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

$(getElementById(id)) не работает.
Подскажите пожалуйста метод или функцию

Comment: `$('#idName')`, `$('.className')`, `$('TagName')`. Читай документацию к JS, CSS

Answer (score 1):

в Javascript:

```
document.getElementById(идентификатор элемента)

document.querySelector('тут описание о элемента')
```

например

```
<div id = 'block'>...</div>

let element = document.getElementById('block')
let element = document.querySelector('#block')
```

а в jQuery:

```
$('тут описание о элемента')
```

например

```
<div id = 'block'>...</div>

let element = $('#block')
```

только в любом случае убедитесь, что элемент к этому моменту (к моменту обращения к элементу) существует

Comment: а если id задан в переменной?

Comment: а какая разница? `document.getElementById(myValue)` или `$('#' + myValue)`

Comment: большое спасибо